# Doctrine2 - limit returned associated entities

Tags: php, database, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to limit how many associations will be returned from DB? For example lets say I have following entities:

```
/** @Entity */
Article {
   /** @OneToMany(targetEntity="Comments") */
   private $comments; 
   ...
}

/** @Entity */
Comments { ... }
```

And when iterating over collection of articles I would like to get just 5 recent comments. (there could be 100 or more in total). I fetch the collection from a custom repository using QueryBuilder.

In practice I would use something like this:

```
$articles = $em->getRepository("Article")->findArticles($commentLimit, ...);
foreach($articles as $article) {
   foreach($article->getComments() as $comment) {
       //loop will iterate just $commentLimit times
       echo $comment->getText();
   }
}
```

Is it possible to do this within a signle query?

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case I would use

```
/** @Entity */
Article {
   /**
    * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Comments", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
    * @OrderBy({"lastModified" = "DESC"})
    */
   private $comments; 
}
```

`@OrderBy` [just sorts the fetched elements by one or more attributes](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/annotations-reference.html#orderby) in this case by their last modified date.
Using `EXTRA_LAZY` on collections changes their behavior, as some of the methods won't initialize the entire collection, but just some pieces of it.
It is the case of [`Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection#slice($start, $end)`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/PersistentCollection.php#L750), which you could use in your example to just load the first elements:

```
$articles = $em->getRepository("Article")->findArticles(...);
foreach($articles as $article) {
   foreach($article->getComments()->slice(0, $commentLimit) as $comment) {
       echo $comment->getText();
   }
}
```

If what you want to do is fetch the last 5 comments regardless of the article, then you should use [DQL](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html).

Comment: The problem is that your code will produce 1 query for each article. (because of the `fetch="EXTRA_LAZY"`) I would like to fetch all in 1 or 2 queries.